# How to compare fit of discrete process with discrete underlying process?

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, smoothing

I am basically looking for an equivalent to something like an $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a model on a dataset that is itself simply a collection of points. That is, if my data set is (trivial example):

```
x <- 1:10

y <- c(1,6,3,7,7,10,4, 7, 8, 10)
```

and my 6-point fit grid is:

```
x.fit <- c(1,2,4,6,8,10)
y.fit <- c(1,4,6,6,7,10)
```

how might I compare this fit, with 6 coordinate pairs, with one of fewer or more? Basically I am looking to minimize the number of points I need to represent the underlying process with the fit, while ensuring the fit still models the data well. This 'well' is what I am looking to statistically analyze, so that I can plot my model with $N$ points from 1 to `length(process$x)`, and find a balance.

I am uncertain how to process because I am used to fitting polynomials or predictor point-invariate models. Any help would be greatly appreciated.